# How to hide Bottom navigation Bar in splash Screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
Scaffold(bottomBar = {

    if (currentRoute(navController) != Screen.SplashScreen.route)
```

//        AnimatedVisibility(visible= bottomBarState.value ) {
BottomAppBar(modifier = modifier
.height(80.dp)
.padding(5.dp)
.clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(60.dp)), containerColor = Color.Gray, tonalElevation = 5.dp) {
items.forEach { items ->

```
                val selected = items.route == backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route
                NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = items.route == navController.currentDestination?.route,
                    onClick = { onItemClick(items) },
                    icon = {
                        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                            if (items.badgeCount > 0) {

                                BadgedBox(badge = {
                                    Text(text = items.badgeCount.toString())


                                }) {
                                    Icon(imageVector = items.icon, contentDescription = items.name)
                                }
                            } else {
                                    Icon(imageVector = items.icon, contentDescription = items.name)
                            }

                            if (selected) {

                                   Text(text = items.name, textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 10.sp)
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                        selectedIconColor = Color.Green,
                        unselectedIconColor = Color.Red
                        ,
                        selectedTextColor = Color.Green,
                        indicatorColor = Color.DarkGray
                    )
                )
            }

        }
    //}

}){
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

Your extension function:

```
@Stable
@Composable
private fun NavController.shouldShowBottomNavigationAsState(shouldHideRoutes: List<String>): State<Boolean> {
    val shouldShowBottomNavigation = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    DisposableEffect(this) {
        val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (shouldHideRoutes.any { it == destination.route }) {
                shouldShowBottomNavigation.value = true
            } else {
                shouldShowBottomNavigation.value = false
            }
        }
        addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
        onDispose {
            removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
        }
    }
    return shouldShowBottomNavigation
}
```

Usage:

```
val useBottomNavigation by navController.shouldShowBottomNavigationAsState(
   listOf(
      "route1","route2" // put your routes that you want to hide bottom navigation view
   ),
)

if (useBottomNavigation) {
   // your bottom navigation composable
}
```